# codeigniter - Redirect user after verify activation code

Tags: codeigniter

i have send 4 number activation code with sms for user and i want if code is true redirect to user dashboard.
how to do it?

my code:

```
    function VerifyCode()
{
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $sms = $this->input->post('sms');
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $VerifyCode = $this->User_model->ch($sms);
    if ($VerifyCode == true) {
        session_start();
        redirect('UserPanel/Dashboard');
    } else {
        echo "fail!";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work why? Errors? Undesired behavior? What happens?

Comment: simply starting the session isn't a way to log someone in fyi

Comment: redirect() should do it. is it an ajax form?

Comment: not a way to use session : read this first : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you:**

Load ur `session` library and `url` helper (if not loaded) in your `autoload.php` like this :

```
/* for session */
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

/* for url helper if not*/
$autolaod['helper'] = array('url');
```

And your `VerifyCode` method should be like this :

```
function VerifyCode()
{
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $sms = $this->input->post('sms');
    $VerifyCode = $this->User_model->ch($sms);
    if ($VerifyCode === TRUE) 
    {
        redirect('UserPanel/Dashboard');
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "fail!";
    }
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: tnx dude but i want if verofy code is == TRUE redirect to userpanel

Comment: can u show me the method where u want to redirect with controller name

Comment: i send data in array to set_userdata function and logged_in is False then in VerifyCode function if Verify code is true... logged in => true and load view 
public function VerifyCode()
    {
        $this->load->view('VerifySMS');
        $sms = $this->input->post('sms');
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $VerifyCode = $this->User_model->ch($sms);
        if ($VerifyCode == true) {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('logged_in' => TRUE));
            $this->load->view('UserPanel/dashboard');
        } else {
            echo "fail!";
        }
    }

Comment: u r setting `logged_in` after the `$VerifyCode == true` check that is why not getting ur session, pls set session before checking the session or when user sign in